# How to install GExiv2 on a virtualenv?

Tags: python, image, python-2.7, python-imaging-library, exiv2

I installed [this library](http://redmine.yorba.org/projects/gexiv2/wiki) with:

```
sudo apt-get install libexiv2-dev libgexiv2-2 gir1.2-gexiv2-0.4
```

And I was able to load the Python module:

```
from gi.repository import GExiv2
```

The problem comes with virtualenv. I need to use this library inside a virtualenv and I don't know how to install it, since there is no `pip` package for this.

I tried to make a symbolic link between the system wide installed library and the virtualenv lib folder with no results:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 dnavarro dnavarro   25 jul  4 15:42 girepository-1.0 -> /usr/lib/girepository-1.0
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, I was looking a better solution, but finally I made a symbolic link inside my virtualenv lib directory and it imports `GExiv2` without errors :

```
$ cd virtualenv
$ cd lib/python2.7/
$ ln -s /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi
```

Answer (score 1):

I use `mkvirtualenv` from [`virtualenvwrapper`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenvwrapper) package to create virtual environments. The `--system-site-packages` option links the public packages installed on the system to the new virtual environment.